# Lstlistoflistings empty even though .lol file contains content

Tags: listings

I am finally asking my own question here, since I really cannot find an answer to my problem after 5 days of searching the web:

For some reason my `\lstlistoflistings` command does not produce any output in the pdf. The .lol file does have contenc though.

Here is my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[parskip=half,fontsize=11.5pt,a4wide,bibliography=totocnumbered,listof=totocnumbered]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

\definecolor{mGreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{mGray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mPurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backgroundColour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

\begin{document}

\lstdefinestyle{CStyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backgroundColour},   
    commentstyle=\color{mGreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{mGray},
    stringstyle=\color{mPurple},
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2,
    language=C,

\vspace{1em}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Java-GUI Automatisierung Pseudocode, language=C, escapeinside={(*}{*)}, style=CStyle]
...
\end{lstlisting}
\vspace{1em}

\vspace{1em}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Java-\ac{GUI}: Speicher Aufräumen Pseudocode},label=cleanpseudo, language=C, escapeinside={(*}{*)}, style=CStyle]
...
\end{lstlisting}
\vspace{1em}

\vspace{1em}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Java-\ac{GUI}: Speicher aktuelle Simulation abbrechen Pseudocode},label=cancelpseudo, language=C, escapeinside={(*}{*)}, style=CStyle]
modbusConnect()
modbusWriteCancelCommand()
modbusDisconnect()
\end{lstlisting}
\vspace{1em}

\vspace{1em}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Java-\ac{GUI}: Speicher aktuelle Logdatei herunterladen Pseudocode},label=latestpseudo, language=C, escapeinside={(*}{*)}, style=CStyle]
...
\end{lstlisting}
\vspace{1em}

\pagebreak
\rhead{LISTINGS}
\lstlistoflistings
```

This produces the following .lol file:

```
\contentsline {lstlisting}{\numberline {1}Java-GUI Automatisierung Pseudocode}{29}{lstlisting.1}%
\contentsline {lstlisting}{\numberline {2}Java-GUI Speicher Aufräumen Pseudocode}{30}{lstlisting.2}%
\contentsline {lstlisting}{\numberline {3}Java-GUI Speicher aktuelle Simulation abbrechen Pseudocode}{30}{lstlisting.3}%
\contentsline {lstlisting}{\numberline {4}Java-GUI Speicher aktuelle Logdatei herunterladen Pseudocode}{30}{lstlisting.4}%
```

My Listings page is empty though:

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Update:
I have created a new Overleaf project and in this one it works for me as well. I have noticed a difference in the .lol files, maybe this is the cause?
My original lol file in my main project ends with `{lstlisting.x}` while the new one looks like this:

````
\contentsline {lstlisting}{\numberline {2}Java-GUI: Speicher Aufräumen Pseudocode}{1}{}%
\contentsline {lstlisting}{\numberline {3}Java-GUI: Speicher aktuelle Simulation abbrechen Pseudocode}{1}{}%
\contentsline {lstlisting}{\numberline {4}Java-GUI: Speicher aktuelle Logdatei herunterladen Pseudocode}{1}{}%```
````

Comment: please add packages needed to Your MWE

Comment: I have added the packages listings and xcolor, which I use. I think they should be the only used ones in that passage

Comment: I get the listing. Did you compile twice?

Comment: I have created a new Overleav project and in this one it works for me as well. I have noticed a difference in the .lol files, maybe this is the cause? I jus added an update to my question.

Comment: Doesn't anybody have a clue?